# Doxygen and VHDL digraph, only one graph showing

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

Running doxygen over a VHDL file and I wish to display two digraphs (for example two state machines).

The HTML output of doxygen will only ever show one graph, and indeed the output directories only show one graph.

Examples (not working):

```
--! @dot
--! digraph "sm1" {
--! S1 -> S2;
--! }
--! digraph "sm2" {
--! S2 -> S2;
--! }
--! @enddot
```

Another not working:

```
--! @dot
--! digraph "sm1" {
--! S1 -> S2;
--! }
--! @enddot

--! @dot
--! digraph "sm2" {
--! S2 -> S2;
--! }
--! @enddot
```

When doing this in a "C" file the output works as expected (I get two graphs).

Can anyone please elaborate why this is not working in VHDL?

Thanks
Lachlan.

Comment: We have here 2 issues: 1) 2 digraphs in one @dot command, this results in one file for the dot command and this is, as far as I know, not supported by the dot command. 2) second example, this is probably due to the fact that the comment block is split. When removing the empty line it is working for me (doxygen 1.8.10)

Comment: Thanks for your support, I found too that when you have an empty line above the @dot command it does not work. I removed the empty lines and I am able to have multiple graphs per file.  The only issue now is that the graphs are no longer related to a specific process VHDL process when there are multiple graphs per file.  They seem to be randomly located in the resulting doxygen HTML output despite trying various locations (inside process, inside begin, on-top of process, below process, etc.